# Power Series representation around a=0

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

Given a function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ that has a power series representation around the point $a=0$ given by $f(x)=\sum_k x^k$. Does this allow one to conclude that $\frac25=f(-\frac32)=\sum(-1)^k\frac{3^k}{2^k}$?

Comment: No, because $-3/2$ is outside the region of convergence of the power series. It equals to $f(x)$ only for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Thank you very much..So |x|<1 is the region of covergence

Comment: Another popular use of the formula is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n = -1$.  False in the usual metric, but true in the $2$-adic metric.

Comment: What you can do is expand about another point, say $-1$ to get $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_n\frac{(x+1)^n}{2^n}$, hence $\frac{2}{5}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_n\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n}$

Answer (score 1):

Each power series has some radius of convergence $R$, (which in this case, it is easy to see that it is $1$). The convergence radius is a positive real number $R$ which devides the real number line in two distinct regions:

For $|x| \lt R$, the series converges (actually it converges absolutely, which is a stronger kind of convergence), and for $|x| \gt R$ it diverges (does not converge). This fact is true for any power series. What may vary from a power series to the next is what happens when $|x| = R$. However, in this case, since $R = 1$, you actually know that the series does not converge in $x = -3/2$ (by what I stated above). Therefore, you definitely don't have the equality to which you referred.

Hope this helps :).